# two-panel scatter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

For my data.frame `full` below, I'm wondering how to create a two-panel `geom_point` such that on the first panel, we have `ols.(Intercept)` (x-axis) plotted against `hlm.(Intercept)`, AND on the second panel, we have `ols.ses` (x-axis) plotted against `hlm.ses`?

```
library(lme4) 
library(tidyverse)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

fit <- lmer(math~ses+(ses|sch.id), data= hsb)
ch <- unique(hsb$sch.id)

ols <- map_dfr(ch,~coef(lm(math~ses, data=hsb,subset=sch.id==.)))
mlm <- coef(fit)$sch
full <- cbind(ols=ols, hlm=mlm, sch.id=ch)

head(full, n = 1)
     ols.(Intercept)  ols.ses hlm.(Intercept)  hlm.ses sch.id
1224        10.80513 2.508582        11.06002 2.504083   1224
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to achieve this is by making two separate plots and glue them together using e.g. `patchwork`:

```r
library(lme4) 
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

fit <- lmer(math~ses+(ses|sch.id), data= hsb)
ch <- unique(hsb$sch.id)

ols <- map_dfr(ch,~coef(lm(math~ses, data=hsb,subset=sch.id==.)))
mlm <- coef(fit)$sch
full <- cbind(ols=ols, mlm=mlm, sch.id=ch)

p1 <- ggplot(full, aes(`ols.(Intercept)`, `mlm.(Intercept)`)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(full, aes(ols.ses, mlm.ses)) +
  geom_point()

p1 + p2
```

[image]

And as a second approach with some data wrangling one can achieve a similar plot using `facet_wrap`:

```r
library(lme4) 
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(tidyverse)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

fit <- lmer(math~ses+(ses|sch.id), data= hsb)
ch <- unique(hsb$sch.id)

ols <- map_dfr(ch,~coef(lm(math~ses, data=hsb,subset=sch.id==.)))
mlm <- coef(fit)$sch
full <- cbind(ols=ols, mlm=mlm, sch.id=ch)

full %>% 
  pivot_longer(- sch.id, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(var, into = c("var1", "category"), sep = "\\.") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var1, values_from = value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ols, mlm)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ category)
```

[image]

Comment: So, but couldn't we use a `facet_wrap()`?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. But  yes this could be done.

Comment: I mean to achieve the exact same thing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that you can get exactly the same result using facet_wrap. However, I just added one `facet_wrap` option.

Comment: Just add `nrow = 1,scales = 'free'` to your facet_wrap

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I missed to add `scales="free"`. What I meant with "not exactly" was that there are still differences like no title on both x-axis, no y-axis on each plot, ... Sometimes we want just that and this is to the best of my knowledge not possible with facet_wrap. Best S.

Answer (score 2):

An option with facets. The solution from **@stefan** was really nice and quick. You could set an entire data pipeline by smartly separating your strings and then after reshaping you can have the desired variables in a format to be plotted using `facet_wrap()`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Plot
full %>% select(-sch.id) %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  separate(name,c('V1','V2'),sep='\\.') %>%
  arrange(V2,V1) %>%
  group_by(V2,V1) %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V1,values_from=value) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=ols,y=mlm))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(.~V2,nrow = 1,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That#s the advantage of using patchwork. You save the data wrangling part. (; Best S.

Comment: @stefan Yeah, you were the fastest on replaying. I was astonished! :) King regards!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer using `patchwork`, you can plot them as two separate `ggplot()` graphs and then put them side-by-side with the `plot_grid()` function from the `cowplot` package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html